# How to select one specific dictionary in Winedt?

Tags: winedt, dictionaries

I installed a Spanish dictionary on Winedt long ago, but now I'm writing in English and I would like to use just the English spelling dictionary, I don't want it to mark words as correct because they exist in Spanish but no in English. Is it possible to select just one dictionary on Winedt?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You replace the spanish dictionary with the english, which you find [here](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html) -> [InstallDict](http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/InstallDict.html).  - Options > Dictionary Manager...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Show the "Options Interface" (Options -> Options Interface)

   [image]
2. In the "Options Interface", double-click the "Word Lists" item (`Dictionaries.ini` gets opened)
3. You should be able to locate some lines like

   ```
   DICTIONARY="Spanish"
     FILE="%b\Dict\Spanish\es.dic"
     ENABLED=1
     MODE_FILTER=""
     LOAD_ON_START=1
     SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
     ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
     USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
     ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1
   ```

   In `MODE_FILTER` add `ES` so to have

   ```
     MODE_FILTER="ES"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

Now the Spanish dictionary is enabled only for documents containing `ES` in their mode.

This means that your Spanish TeX documents must have the extension `TeX:ES`.

To achieve that, on all your documents written in Spanish, double-click on `TeX` in the status bar:

[image]

The Document Settings Dialog gets opened.

[image]

In the text field "Document Mode" write `TeX:ES` and press OK.

That's all.